# How to read the rest in Pretty MIDI?

Tags: python, midi

I am using Pretty MIDI in Python. Currently, I want to use pretty midi, a python tool to read the MIDI pitch and length. https://craffel.github.io/pretty-midi/. However, I found that the MIDI will skip the rest and jump to the next note directly. For example, this is the score.
[image]

After reading "G note" in the third measure, it will jump to the "C note" in the fifth measure without any blank time. In other words, the midi will ignore the rest automatically.
Here is the result that pretty midi output.

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I just want to note that this is wrong: _the midi will ignore the rest automatically_. MIDI doesn't ignore rests. Every event in a MIDI file has a delta-time which is the offset from previous event. So if you have a rest, its length will just be written as delta-time of the first event after rest.

Comment: @Maxim I thought I am wrong in the first. However, the result really skips the blank. I've attached the result above.